# Anylogic : Setting resourcepool home location (nodes)

Tags: anylogic

I want to change the home location within a resource pool using code.

Although I can build the model successfully the code has no effect.

The code I'm using is:

INode[] fl_nd = {forkliftHome2, forkliftHome};
if (p_flh==1){forklifts.set_homeNodes(fl_nd);};

where p_flh is a checkbox option

The resourcepool default is :

[default home locations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4H5ic.png)

Comment: I will say that this is a bug in AnyLogic... You can't currently change the home location on run time... this set_homeNodes function has never worked....

Comment: Thanks Felipe, I will find another way.

Answer (score 0):

It is not true. set_homeNodes function has worked. I have zon's: z1 & z2.

```
Node[] nodesDay = {z1};
Node[] nodesNotDay = {z2}
int n;
n=getHourOfDay();
if ((n>7) && (n<18)) 
    park1.set_homeNodes(nodesDay);
else 
    park2.set_homeNodes(nodesNotDay);
```